# How to use a boolean field in a template?

Tags: python, html, django

So I am trying to create some moderation in my app. A users post should be false when the create it and a moderator must come in and set it to true for it to go live.

I have added the field into my models. But I am struggling to get the true ones to display on my template.

MODELS:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    live = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

VIEWS:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/index.html"
```

I know I need to use an if statement but I am not sure how to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to override the queryset in the view to only fetch live posts.

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(live=True)
    template_name = "public/index.html"
```

Now you don't need to change the template at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an if statement in the template.

```
{% for object in object_list %}

    {% if object.live %}
        <div>
          // Here you can put your Post 
        </div>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```